# How do I show a left inverse of a bounded linear operator on Banach space?

Tags: operator-theory, inverse, spectral-theory

If $A$ is a bounded linear operator on a Banach space X, with a left inverse $A_l^{-1}$, and P is a projection (also on X), how do I show that $A_l^{-1}P$ is also a left inverse of A (i.e. $A_l^{-1}PA=I$, the identity operator)?

Answer (score 0):

In general and without further assumptions, $A_l^{-1}PA\neq I$. Take $A\neq0$ for which some $A_l^{-1}$ exists. And take the projection of $X$ onto the subspace $\{0\}$. Then $A_l^{-1}P=0$. (So you need to assume $P$ is a projection onto a subspace that incorporates $A(X)$).

Comment: True. Assuming the range of $P$ is the range of $A$ then, how can I show that $A_l^{-1}PA=I$?

Comment: Well, in this case and since $P$ is a projection we have $Px=x$ for all $x\in A(X)$ and therefore $PA$ actually coincides with $A$!

Comment: Why does $P$ being a projection imply $Px=x$?

Comment: If $x\in P(X)$ (which we assumed since $x\in A(X)\subset P(X)$, then there exists a $y\in X$ with $y=Px$. Then $Px=P(Py)=Py=x$ because $P$ is a projections.